# OpenIso8583Net field 95 conversion to human readable format?

Tags: c#, .net, iso8583, openiso8583.net

I am very new to binary conversions. I have Field 95 coming in below format - total 42 bytes. below field represent $400. Can you please help, how can i convert it to $400 value?

> 000000040000000000000000000000000000000000

Template definition:

```
    var template = new Template{ ...
            { AuthBit._095_REPLACEMENT_AMOUNTS, AuthFieldDescriptor.EbcdicFixed(42, FieldValidators.Ans) },..}

byte[] bitmap = msg.ToMsg();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out DE 95 is represented as 9999999999.99.
So getting a substring of 12 on the returned value i.e.000000040000000000000000000000000000000000 resolves the issue.

> Substring of 12 would be 0000000400.00 which is $400.00